# IKVM C# Tika Implementation - NoClassDefFoundError - sun.java2d.Disposer

Tags: java, c#, noclassdeffounderror, apache-tika, ikvm

I have a small library that utilizes IKVM to run Tika (1.2) for the purposes of extracting text and metadata for use within Lucene. I grab document and image paths from a CMS we are using, and pass them through here:

```
public TextExtractionResult Extract(string filePath)
    {

        var parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        var metadata = new Metadata();
        var parseContext = new ParseContext();
        Class parserClass = parser.GetType();
        parseContext.set(parserClass, parser);

        try
        {
            // Attempt to fix ImageParser "NoClassDefFoundError"
            java.lang.System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");

            var file = new File(filePath);
            var url = file.toURI().toURL();
            using (InputStream inputStream = TikaInputStream.get(url, metadata))
            {
                parser.parse(inputStream, getTransformerHandler(), metadata, parseContext);
                inputStream.close();
            }

            return AssembleExtractionResult(_outputWriter.toString(), metadata);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Extraction of text from the file '{0}' failed.".ToFormat(filePath), ex);
        }
    }
```

Only when the files are `.png`, it bombs with this error:

[image]

It seems as though it most likely coming from Tika's `ImageParser`.

For those who are interested - You can see `getTransformerHandler()` here:

```
private TransformerHandler getTransformerHandler()
    {

        var factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance() as SAXTransformerFactory;
        TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "text");
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "UTF-8");

        _outputWriter = new StringWriter();
        handler.setResult(new StreamResult(_outputWriter));
        return handler;
    }
```

I have looked around and keep being pointed in the direct of running headless, so I already tried that with no luck. Because this is a C# implementation in IKVM, is something missing? It works on all other documents as far as I can tell (`.jpeg`, `.docx`, `.pdf`, etc.).

Thanks to those who know more about Tika + IKVM implementations than I do.

Comment: Tika 1.2 is absolutely ancient! What happens when you upgrade to something vaguely recent?

Comment: @Gagravarr - I will update and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @Gagravarr - I updated to the latest Tika .NET lib, and other dependencies, and it worked like a charm. Thanks! - If you would like to post an answer I will give it to you.

Comment: If you want something that does this for you check out TikaOnDotnet. https://kevm.github.io/tikaondotnet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Tika 1.2 was released back on 17 July 2012, and [there have been a lot of fixes and improvements](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/tika/CHANGES-1.12.txt) since then

You should upgrade to the most [recent version of Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/download.html) (1.12 as of writing), and that should solve your issue

Comment: I am seeing this issue with tika 2.4.1 with DOCX files.

Comment: @user169771 All the Apache Tika unit tests are passing just fine - https://ci-builds.apache.org/job/Tika/job/tika-main-jdk18/ - which suggests that it's something wrong with your environment or how you installed Tika...